# left join subquery with limit returns null

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I am trying to create a query to see when a customer ordered/bought something the first time, the last time and which channel did he use the first and last time (email, fax, phone ..).

I got this SQLFiddle (which is working as intended)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9e947f/17

But on my server

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit
```

I get a `null` when I add the `limit 1` in the subquery

This is the query

```
SELECT
  c.customerid,
  least(min(o.date), min(f.date))    AS firstbuydate,
  greatest(max(o.date), max(f.date)) AS lastbuydate,
  sub_max.type                       AS lasttype
FROM customer c
  LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.customerid = c.customerid
  LEFT JOIN invoices f ON f.customerid = c.customerid
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               customerid,
               type,
               max(date)
             FROM invoice
             GROUP BY type, customerid
             ORDER BY max(date) DESC
             LIMIT 1
            ) AS sub_max ON (c.customerid = sub_max.customerid)
WHERE c.customerid = 5
GROUP BY c.customerid, sub_max.type;
```

and the output

```
customerid  firstbuydate    lastbuydate lasttype
5           2010-11-04      2012-09-26  <null>
```

without the `limit 1` I get the obvious

```
customerid  firstbuydate    lastbuydate lasttype
5           2010-11-04      2012-09-26  EMAI
5           2010-11-04      2012-09-26  PHON
```

Result of the subquery with and without the `limit 1`

```
customerid  type    date
5           EMAI    2012-09-26
5           PHON    2011-12-20

customerid  type    date
5           EMAI    2012-09-26
```

I know why the subquery can't work, is there a way to reference the `c.customerid` inside the subquery?

Another way:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c83df/13

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119041/discussion-between-user3137702-and-beig).

Comment: Please put what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link, including a [mre]. Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Please don't edit a question in a way that invalidates reasonable answer posts. PS Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Please edit this to clearly ask about 1 bad query without invalidating answers.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
i solved it by using the row_number() function :

```sql
select *
from myfirsttable mft
left outer join (
  select t.field1, t.field2, 
  row_number() over (partition by t.field1 order by t.date) as rnb 
  from mytable t
) t1 on t1.field1=mft.field1 
and t1.rnb=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by setting a limit in the subquery, then joining on the returned value which is not guaranteed to contain the id you are looking to join. If you use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` and filter out customerid inside the subquery, you will get the correct result.

```sql
SELECT
  c.customerid,
  least(min(o.date), min(f.date))    AS firstbuydate,
  greatest(max(o.date), max(f.date)) AS lastbuydate,
  sub_max.type                       AS lasttype
FROM customer c
  LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.customerid = c.customerid
  LEFT JOIN invoices f ON f.customerid = c.customerid
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT
               customerid,
               type,
               max(date)
             FROM invoice
             WHERE c.customerid = customerid
             GROUP BY type, customerid
             ORDER BY max(date) DESC
             LIMIT 1
            ) AS sub_max ON true
WHERE c.customerid = 5
GROUP BY c.customerid, sub_max.type;
```